# Can I connect multiple bare wires to one DC Power connector?

Tags: dc

I need to install a HDCVI CCTV system which comes with 4 male DC connectors )left in the image below) and 1 female DC connector (right). Supposedly, the 4 cameras the system has all use the same power supply, to which the female connector attaches to. The system uses UTP cables.

My question now is: Do I connect all cameras UTP bare wires to the female connector just by twisting them together (minding + and - of course)? I have googled it, but all I can find is tutorials with one camera, not 4. Thanks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am struggling my self at same situation as yours. 
What I have identified is that you have to make sure you power supply has current enough to cover more current than your whole system need. I am planning to build up a 8 cam cctv and I definitely will use a terminal block to connect all power wires into it and in the other side just two wires from the power supply. 
So answering your question, I'd use one connector per camera and I will definitely connect all cam power cables in same power supply output (thorough terminal block).